# Very low battery-life in specific WiFi

Tags: wi-fi, battery-life, multiple-devices

Hello fellow Android Enthusiasts.

I have a problem that has been bugging me for a very long time:
Whenever I leave devices at my workplace overnight, the battery is completely drained the next day.
This occurs on any Android device and any of those devices' batteries last completely normal in any other location. This is exceptionally strange with tablets which batteries last for weeks in standby mode.
The devices are not connected to anything over night via cables.

The only thing I can think of that is different between work and anywhere else is the WiFi.

Those are my devices that I could observe the behavior on:

- Sony Xperia Compact Z5
- Samsung Galaxy Tab S2
- Google Pixel C
- LGE Nexus 4
- Google Nexus

The range of Android Versions goes from 5.1 to 7.1.1.

Can such a behavior be caused by the WiFi? I was thinking of *connection loss and reconnection* iterations. But I think I would have noticed such problems while being at work. Any other ideas out here?

Comment: While WiFi is turned on and no connection is available then the phone keeps on searching for a wireless connection. This certainly leads to draining of battery.

Comment: The WiFi at the workplace is up 24/7. Also I never switch WiFi off on my phone when walking around outside and it never drains the battery as extreme as it does it at work.

Comment: Is there a single WiFi connection available at your workplace or multiple?

Comment: There are plenty of WiFi. But there are also plenty of WiFi at home where the battery-life is normal.

Comment: Device connects automatically to the WiFi with better signal strength. At you work place the signal strength of WiFis might vary, resulting into change of connections leading to battery drain, which might not be the case at your home.

Comment: 1. Firstly, we are assuming it is Wi-Fi related ( though I can't think of anything else)- turning off the WiFi to see battery drop would confirm 2. [Install this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.farproc.wifi.analyzer) to see the time graph of WiFi strength at night- of it is very weak, that could be causing the problem 3. Have you scheduled backups like Google, Dropbox, whatsup etc to the cloud at each early hours / night time ? This could be causing significant drain 4. Check if you have scheduled anything else to run at night

Comment: I will experiment with the suggestions of 1 and 2. I don't think that synchronization is the key here since it does this at home, as well.
I will reply once I've testet it, which may take at least a day.

Comment: Please tag @ me, else I may miss seeing your response